# Python Pylance unresolved import from class exposed by __init__.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, python-module

### Issue

I'm working on updating an Python library to use modern versions of Python (the `Equation` library) and am having trouble with Pylance when importing from the module. The base form of the library also had this issue, but for reference, here's my fork: [Antyos/Equation](https://github.com/Antyos/Equation).

As the library describes, you are supposed to be able to import the `Expression` class like so:

```py
from Equation import Expression

e = Expression("sin(x+y^2)")
```

This code works, however, Pylance will give the following error:

```
"Expression" is unknown import symbol Pylance(reportGeneralTypeIssues)
```

If I import the code as follows, I don't receive the error and I can get type hints.

```py
from Equation.core import Expression
```

### My Understanding

I roughly understand the issue--as shown in the file structure below, it makes sense that `from Equation.core import Expression` would work. I also understand that `__init__.py` is exposing the `Expression` class to the top level of the module. (I still don't totally get how this part works and I can't seem to find the right page/section detailing it.)

```sh
Equation
├─ __init__.py
├─ _info.py
├─ core.py  # Contains Expression()
├─ equation_base.py
├─ equation_scipy.py
├─ similar.py
└─ util.py
```

While I'm pretty sure I could get around this issue by writing a stub (`*.pyi`) file, it seems redundant (to me) to create a stub file for a class that I already have direct access to; why would I need to redefine something that's already there? However, it is also likely that I don't completely understand how stub files / module imports work and this is the right way.

I'm sure this issue has been addressed before, but I think I've been using the wrong terminology. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `__init__.py` I believe you are performing relative import:

```
try:
    from Equation.core import Expression
except ImportError:
    from core import Expression
```

The correct way to perform relative import here is to put `.` in front of `core` like this `.core`.

For example:

```
try:
    from Equation.core import Expression
except ImportError:
    from .core import Expression
```

This fixes Pylance when I tried it.

Spec reference: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks!
That code was from the original library. I had no idea what it was supposed to be doing, but of course it makes total sense that it was supposed to be a relative import.

Comment: Thanks! Easy to get lost in github issues, when the problem is basic.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a problem in which I was having the following error within vscode:

```
"some_module" is unknown import symbol
```

It turned out to be that the folder structure where the module was contained changed but the way to import it remained. The problem was that some old pycache existed in my local working copy within the old folder structure. After removing all of them, pylance started to work normally.